# How to perform Multiple callback methods parallely

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback

I am using callback methods while integrating web services. Any one can suggest, how can I use multiple callback methods parallely,

I know we can do integrate multiple web service by creating

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

//block 1
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [self getUserProfiles];
});

//block 2
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    // block 2 will get notify, after block 1 complete his task.
}
```

But how can perform the above, using callback?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: use block(closure) for call multiple method parallely

Comment: @KKRocks, can you please give a example. So that, i can get it

Comment: ok in objective c ?

Comment: Yes. i am comfortable in objective c

Answer (score 2):

You can try block for your goal

Create method that return block

```
-(void)getResponseWithUrl:(NSString *)url AndWithPararameter:(NSDictionary *)parameter WithCallback:(void(^)(BOOL success, id responseObject))callback{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,url] parameters:parameter progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        callback(YES,responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        callback(NO,nil);
      }];
}
```

**invoke this way**

```
[self getResponseWithUrl:@"URL" AndWithPararameter:@{@"parameters":@""} WithCallback:^(BOOL success, id responseObject) {

}];
```