# How to get data from API with Async way.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to get data and show in tableView. As I have to send Request in viewDidLoad. But it took much time while loading my data, so I need it to be done in async way.
Any Suggestions or Recommendations.?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //------castApi----//
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self tableView2]setDelegate:self ];
    [[self tableView2]setDataSource:self];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *castString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%@/credits?api_key=c4bd81709e87b12e609433c49",movieIDinString];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:castString];

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection){
        webData=  [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%@/credits?api_key=c4bd81709e87b12e609433c49",movieIDinString]];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

}];
```

Comment: What should be kept in sendAsynchronousRequest?? Sorry for stupid question as I'm newbie :)

Comment: your request url Boss:)  @SheikhMuhammadAmaan-Ullah

Comment: what is the problem with url request ?

Comment: FYI - don't use `NSURLConnection`. Most of it is deprecated. Use `NSURLSession`.

Comment: yes but in question NSURLConnection is mentioned so answer is as per question .

Comment: @KKRocks [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

}]; this is deprecated

Comment: ok not problem try this using Afnetworking 3.0 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40300141/3901620

Comment: if you dont want to use library than you should use NSURLSession. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession